# fwrite in binary mode of ints not writing proper number of bytes

Tags: c

I am not able to understand the fread fwrite behavior of the following code snippet, exemplified by the code is straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int   temp[100] = {0};
    int   i;

    fp = fopen("testdata.bin","wb");
    if( fp!= NULL ) {
        fwrite( arr,sizeof(int), 10, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    fp = fopen("testdata.bin","rb");
    if( fp!= NULL ) {
        fread( temp,sizeof(int), 10, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("%#x,",temp[i]);
    printf("\b \n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output on stdout is:

```
0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x9,0xa,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

which makes sense. However, when I open the `testdata.bin` file, I see only two bytes for value (int) where I expect 4 bytes as size of int is 4 on my machine.

Here is the content of testdata.bin:

```
0x00000001: 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 08 00
0x00000010: 09 00 0a 00
```

I would have expected

```
0x00000001: 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't report in your code whether the program was able to open the file for writing.  You simply don't write in it if the `fopen()` fails.  Check the return from `fopen()`, and for debugging, report on its status.

Comment: Please stop tag spamming. This is C code, not C++. They are not the same language just because they both start with *c*, any more than a *cat* and a *car* are the same because they start with *ca*.

Comment: @KenWhite it looks like valid C++ to me.  https://godbolt.org/g/4qQpFQ

Comment: I think you need to print out the size of an `int` on your machine.  It looks to me like you're managing to use 2-byte `int`.  The output and input are agreeing.  Use `printf("sizeof(int) = %zu\n", sizeof(int));` to ensure that what you think is happening actually is happening.

Comment: Please specify which language you are interested in an answer for -- C or C++ and adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: @xaxxon: Because it compiles with a C++ compiler does not make it C++ code. C++ code does not compile with a C compiler.

Comment: @xaxxon This is a C code, i did not know i have to mention that in my post (btw i did tag it as c code).

Comment: @VikasYadav don't tag questions with languages other than the one you want an answer for, please.  I've adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler  on my PC size of int is 4 as i mentioned in OP. I ensured. I am not sure how can i prove it here.

Comment: @Vikas, what does `printf("%d\n",sizeof(int))` give you?

Comment: Like I told you — print the value of `sizeof(int)` in the output.  On my machine, I get 4 and output similar to what you expect.  Your code is self-coherent, but the file is half the size you expected; that suggests strongly that your data type is half the size you expected.

Comment: @paxdiablo `printf("%d\n",sizeof(int))` give 4. i already verified this before writing this post, that s what i mentioned earlier as well.

Comment: Okay, put `system("cd")` or `system("pwd")` at the start of your code to make sure you're in the directory you *think* you're in. If you're in an IDE, you may be looking at the wrong (e.g., earlier version of the) file.

Comment: Now _that_ is unexpected.  Maybe you should specify how you demonstrate the data in the file, but that looks mostly OK — except that the offset of the first line should be 0x00000000 and not 0x00000001.  Check the modification time of the file you're looking at, too.  Move or remove the file, even, before running the test program, then check the result file again, and its modification time.

Comment: Did you ever have a version of the code using `short` instead of `int` for the array type?

Comment: the files are latest, checked the timestamps.

Comment: What specific command are you using to display the contents of your data file?  If you change the declaration of the `temp` array to be `unsigned char` instead of `int`, what do you see for your program's output?

Comment: the file size of testdata.bin shows up as 40 bytes, which is good news. maybe my hex-editor plugin for notepad++ is not doing a good job?

Comment: @Patric-Kelly with that change, i see same output as you suggested.

Comment: OK, so with the file size correct, I do indeed think it's your display tool.  Probably just not cnofigured or behaving in the way you expected.

Comment: any recommendation for a better reliable display tool for bin files?

Comment: I wonder why there is a -1 vote to my question, if i know, i can try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `fwrite` is working fine.  Change the declaration of `temp` so the type is an array of one-byte unsigned characters:

```
unsigned char temp [100] = {0} ;
```

The current version of the code displays a four-byte integer each time in the print statement.  This will confirm that the contents of the file are as you expect.  On my machine:

```
0x1,0,0,0,0x2,0,0,0,0x3,0,0,0,0x4,0,0,0,0x5,0,0,0,0x6,0,0,0,0x7,0,0,0,0x8,0,0,0,0x9,0,0,0,0xa,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I tried the suggested change and I do see the same output as shown above! Which means the code is right.